# How to fix orientation and motion inside iframe (cross-origin) on IOS 12.2+?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to resolve issue on IOS 12.2+ with motion and orientation access (gyroscope) inside iframe which is placed on another domain. I am stuck and don't know how to fix it. Do you have solutions or any reference? Thx for help.

I tried use allow attribute in iframe like this:

```
<iframe allow="fullscreen; gyroscope; accelerometer; magnetometer; vr; xr"></iframe>
```